# Merging ConstraintViolation set from validator.validate with ConstraintValidatorContext

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Is there some method (other than foreach, but good foreach could be sufficient), to return messages from `validator.valid` from custom `ConstraintValidator` ?

Simple example (yes, I'm trying to do conditional validation)

```java
@TestFormConstraint
public class TestForm {

    @NotEmpty
    String foo;

    boolean checkBar = false;

    @NotEmpty(groups=CheckBarGroup.class)
    String bar;

    //getters & setters ...
}
```

```java
public class TestFormValidator 
        implements ConstraintValidator<TestFormConstraint, TestForm> {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTestForm constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TestForm form, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(form.isCheckBar()){
            Set<ConstraintViolation<TestForm>> con = 
                    validator.validate(form, CheckBarGroup.class);
            if(!con.isEmpty()){
                //ok, so what to do here? iterate over con and for each msg 
                //call context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate ?
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may use groups for such cases.
So, remove `checkBar` field and just specify or not `CheckBarGroup`.

like

`validator.validate(testForm)` or `validator.validate(testForm, CheckBarGroup.class, Default.class)`